# if statement with decimal digits not recognized in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an If statement to change the colour of the inner text if the integer value is <=10.0

```
info_1[1].innerText        = energystatus[1];  //energystatus[1] value is a string type

var energystatusint1 = parseInt(energystatus[1]) //converting to int

if (energystatusint1 <= 10.0){

    info_1[1].style.color  ="rgb(255,83,73)"; 

}
```

But what's happening now is that the text colour changes when the value is 10.9 and below, and not <=10.0,
I have tried putting "==" and still that's the result. I think the if statement is not reading the decimal places, but just values before the decimal. I don't know if my conversion from string to integer is 100 percent right?

I know that in normal cases it would work because i have tried this simple code
with changing the values of  variable " a" around and it works perfectly.

```
 var a =10.5;  //tried lower numbers as well
    
    if ( a <=10.1){
    
        console.log("less than 10.1")
    }
```

Can someone correct what I'm doing wrong. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `parseFloat()` instead of a `parseInt()`

Answer (score 2):

You're using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) that will get only take the non decimal value, instead use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```js
    var a ="10.5"; //tried lower numbers as well
    var b=parseInt(a);
    var c=parseFloat(a);
    if ( b <=10.0){
    
        console.log("less or equal than 10.0")
    }else{console.log("greater than 10.0");}
    if (c <=10){
    console.log("less than 10.1")
    }else{console.log("greater than 10.0");}
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` simply truncates the number at the decimal point.

`parseInt('10.9')` gives `10`, and `10 <= 10.0` is `true`.

You need to use `parseFloat(energystatus[1])` or `Number(energystatus[1])` instead.